# How to call async function?

Tags: python, asynchronous, bots, telegram, supabase

I'm new inPython and to learn about this language I decided to create Telegram BOT. I have the problem trying to connect with supabase, idk if the problem is syntax or or am I forgetting something.

I need to get a random document using [RPC](https://supabase.io/docs/reference/javascript/rpc) (Stores Procedures) with this code but I receive an error:

```
/Users/alvarogoederivera/web/python_bot/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telegram/ext/dispatcher.py:555: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'random_quote' was never awaited
  handler.handle_update(update, self, check, context)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

```
import logging
import asyncio
import os
import telegram
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters
from supabase_py import create_client, Client


from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

url: str = os.getenv("SUPABASE_URL")
key: str = os.getenv("SUPABASE_KEY")
token: str = os.getenv("TELEGRAM_TOKEN")

supabase: Client = create_client(url, key)

#Conf Logging
logging.basicConfig(
  level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
)

logger = logging.getLogger()

def start(update):
  logger.info(f"El usuario {update.effective_user['username']}, ha iniciado")
  name = update.effective_user['first_name']
  update.message.reply_text(f"Hola {name} yo soy tu bot")

async def random_quote(update, context):
  quote = await supabase.rpc('get_random_quote', {})
  print(quote)
  # user_id = update.effective_user['id']
  # logger.info(f"el usuario {user_id} ha solicitado una frase")
  # context.bot.sendMessage(chat_id = user_id, parse_mode="MarkdownV2", text=f"_Frase_ *x*")

def echo(update, context):
  user_id = update.effective_user['id']
  logger.info(f"el usuario {user_id} ha enviado un mensaje")
  text = update.message.text
  context.bot.sendMessage(chat_id = user_id, parse_mode="MarkdownV2", text=f"_escribiste_ *{text}*")

if __name__ == "__main__":
  bot = telegram.Bot(token = token)

updater = Updater(bot.token)

dp = updater.dispatcher

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(random_quote({}, {}))

dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("random", random_quote))
dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, echo))

updater.start_polling()

print("BOT LOAD")

updater.idle()
```

Does anyone know how to get the data?

Answer (score 0):

I recently found out how to get the data from supabase, to do so you have to try something like this:

```
data = supabase.table('users').select('id').eq('id', un).execute()
```

or

```
data = supabase.table('users').select('stuff').execute()
```

Essentially what this is saying is that I want it to select the table called users, then I want to select all the id's that are equal to the object called  un

and then once you want to view that data, you use something like this:

```
data.get('data')
```

This wil return everything that matches the value of un:

```
[{'id': 'NotNazuh'}]
```